# Filling a circle gradually from bottom to top

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to create a circular view filling gradually from bottom to top (depending on a percentage), but I have no idea how to achieve this result.

[image]

Is there something already existing ? How can I start doing it?

Comment: A shape by css shape or html canvas or svg and auto increment the inner background value with your desired percentage.

Comment: You probably need a Native Module which draws on to UIView. It is a good question.

Comment: You can write something along the lines of react-native-circular-progress: https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress/blob/master/src/CircularProgress.js

Comment: And some more on ART - http://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-presentation/

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you do it in RN, with a demo on snack - https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/circle-fill - super simple, just basic `<View>` with styling. If you want this animated, its equally easy, let me know and put up another topic and Ill post the animated version there.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.circle}>
          <View style={[styles.circleFill, { height:'25%' }]} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  circle: {
    width: 196,
    height: 196,
    borderRadius: 196 / 2,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  circleFill: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    width: '100%',
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});
```

Screenshot on Android:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I just have a problem with the yellow part: it doesn't cut with the circle shape, so I have the circle and a yellow rectangle at the bottom. Do you know why ?

Comment: @donzmat yes this is a bug in Android, where `overflow: 'hidden'` did not work. It was fixed in I think RN 0.51 - so you will have to upgrade.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, Noitidart. I accept the answer as soon as I upgrade.

Comment: @donzmat Sure thing, and if you want to animate that fill let me know, it'll be a fun question to solve.

Comment: Wow i didn't expect that much. I gladly accept the offer, but there's no hurry :) Do I ask a new question tomorrow ?

Comment: Totally @donzmat I think you would learn a lot from it. Post it up and let me know please, it'll be fun intro to react native.

Comment: @Noitidart how we can animate it ?

Comment: @Noitidart, really thank you, awesome, if only i become  as awesome as you in RN

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in React with CSS.

CSS

```
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

React

```
const Circle = ({pct, color}) => {
  const style = {
    background: `linear-gradient(transparent ${100-pct}%, ${color} ${100-pct}%)`
  };
  return <div className="circle" style={style}></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Circle pct={25} color={'orange'}/>, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-circle-fill-animation-d39uk

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this approach it's working for me. I was wondering if you had any insight into how I could best animate the circle fill?

Comment: @SadBonesMalone You can't CSS animate linear-gradient. But with some CSS tricks you can still use CSS animation.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-circle-fill-animation-d39uk